# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (Bitbucket pipeline)

Tags: sql, laravel, phpunit, bitbucket

I'm running a bitbucket pipeline to execute all the unit test with PHP Unit. When I execute the test on local all of them pass. But on the bitbucket pipeline it always fail. In this case, the tests are related to an external service that we are checking.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

use MyService;

class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Test the dummies in this new system
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testDumies()
    {
        $games = DummyService::getDummies();
        $this->assertTrue(count($dummies) > 0);
    }

    public function testDummiesOfUser()
    {
        $dummies = DummyService::getDummiesOfUser('someemail@mail.com');
        $this->assertTrue(count($dummies) > 0);
    }
}
```

And the following is the service to get the dummies

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;

class DummyService {

    /**
     * Get dummies
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function getDummies() {
        $collection = [];

        $games = $this->getDummiesInUrl('http://my-project/api/v1/platform/dummies');
        foreach($dummies as $dummy) {
            $collection[] = $dummy;
        }

        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the dummies in url
     *
     * @param string $endpoint
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDummiesInUrl($endpoint) {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $res = $client->request('GET', $endpoint);
        $body = $res->getBody();
        $body = json_decode($body, true);
        $data = $body['data'];
        $dummies = $data['dummies'];
        return $dummies;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the dummies of an user
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDummiesOfUser($email) {
        $collection = [];
        $dummies = $this->getDummiesOfUserInUrl('http://myroute/api/v1/platform/dummies/user', $email);
        foreach($dummies as $d) {
            $collection[] = $d;
        }
        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Get gameplays in url
     *
     * @param string $endpoint
     * @param string $email
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDummiesOfUserInUrl($endpoint, $email) {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $res = $client->request('GET', $endpoint, ['query' => ['email' => $email]]);
        $body = $res->getBody();
        $body = json_decode($body, true);
        $data = $body['data'];
        $dummies = $data['dummiess'];
        return $dummies;
    }
}
```

But when that is tested on the bitbucket pipeline I got the following errors:

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client` and `Caused by PDOException:PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]`

Comment: Probably, you don't have all required packages, installed in your bitbucket machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently with the new public version of mysql 8, lots of things have changed. So in order to keep working with your pipelines, I edited my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` and changed the mysql image version from mysql to mysql:5.7.22

```
definitions:
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7.22
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'homestead'
        MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        MYSQL_USER: 'homestead'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'secret'
```

Comment: this is actually something that changed with php 7.2.11 so if you run php 7.2.10 then you will have no problems with mysql 8